# Dynamically added imagebuttons not added to page.Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table with a fixed ImageButton and some ImageButtons added dynamically in Page_Load.  In the page 'View source' they look identical (other than ID):

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <input type="image" name="ctl00$cphMain$ibSel_020" id="cphMain_ibSel_020" src="/Images/Deselected.gif" />
   </td>
   <td>Fixed ImageButton
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <input type="image" name="ctl00$cphMain$ibSel_001" id="cphMain_ibSel_001" src="/Images/Deselected.gif" />
   </td>
   <td>Dynamic ImageButton
   </td>
</tr>
....plus ten more dynamically added ImageButtons ibSel_002 through ibSel_011.
```

In the Page_Load event I am determining which control causes the postback by iterating through page.Request.Form.  If I click the fixed ImageButton, if is found in page.Request.Form as "ibSel_020".  If I click any of the dynamic ImageButtons, the ID is not found.

I know the postback is occuring for all of the ImageButtons because I have it updating (in Page_Load) a label with the ID (for test purposes) -- it is blank for all dynamic ImageButtons and "ibSel_020" for the fixed ImageButton.

How can I can tell which dynamically added ImageButton caused the postback?

Here's some code to generate the ImageButtons:

```
for(int Q = 0; Q < g_zTypes.GetLength(0); Q++){
   TableRow tr = new TableRow();

   TableCell tc = new TableCell(); //Add image button to row

   ImageButton ib = new ImageButton();
   ib.ID = "ibSel_" + Q.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
   ib.ImageUrl = "/Images/Deselected.gif";
   tc.Controls.Add(ib);

   tr.Cells.Add(tc);

   tc = new TableCell(); //Add extra cell to row
   tc.Text = g_zTypes[Q, 1];
   tr.Cells.Add(tc);

   tblType.Rows.Add(tr);
}
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:**

For testing, I wrote a chunk of code to accumulate all the page.Request.Form elements in a string.  At the end of Page_Load I'm Response.Writing zMagic.  Here is the chunk:

```
//=============MAGIC CODE=========================
      Control cF;
      string zF;
      foreach(string zControl in Page.Request.Form){
         //For ImageButtons crop off mouse coordinates property
         if(zControl.EndsWith(".x") || zControl.EndsWith(".y")){
            cF = Page.FindControl(zControl.Substring(0, zControl.Length - 2));
         }
         else{
            cF = Page.FindControl(zControl);
         }
         zF = (cF == null) ? "NULL" : cF.ToString();
        zMagic += "<br />Form[" + zControl + "]=[" + zF + "]<br />";
      }
      zMagic += "[END]";
//================================================
```

I found that the dynamically added ImageButtons were actually present regardless of where in Page_Load I stuck 'Magic Code'.  What was happening was the Page.FindControl() was failing -- but only if I had 'Magic Code' before the code where the dynamic ImageButtons were re-created.

BOTTOM LINE: You can't Page.FindControl(zDynamicControl) until it is re-created.

Comment: How are you generating and adding these buttons?

Comment: Add the code where you create the buttons

Comment: @Murali - Eh, the rendered HTML is in my original post.

Comment: Did you try with **string senderPostBack = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];**?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

[Dynamically bind eventhandler at runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3d01ft1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This should help you get the id of the control which causes the postback.

Inside your EventHandler, you can get the Id of your control like this.

```
void imgBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //((ImageButton)sender).ID
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply RKS.  The table (actually asp:Table) already exists, as does one asp:TableRow where the fixed ImageButton exists.  The dynamic ImageButtons are added to the asp:Table in new asp:TableRow's.

Comment: I actually coded your solution first, but had to abandon it because of the chicken-egg issue.  The EH's don't happen until after Page_Load.  But that is too late because which dynamic ImageButtons are to be added in this rendering depends on which dynamic ImageButton from the previous rendering was clicked.  I hope I'm being clear, and thanks for the suggestion.